# Passing jQuery slider values to GET

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get the values from jQuery slider and pass them trought GET for meta search in Wordpress. Currently with my code below the input field passes this data via url: `&price=Between+5000+and+25000+currency.`

What is the best way for handling/getting this values so I can pass them to my php meta search function.

```
jQuery(function() {

$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 100000,
    values: [ 5000, 25000 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {

        $( "#amount" ).val( "Between " + ui.values[ 0 ] + " and " + ui.values[ 1 ] + " currency.");
    }

});

$( "#amount" ).val( "Between " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + " and " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) + " currency." );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for myself. Still looking for better or more elegant handling of this. Here is my solution:

```
   if( !empty($_GET['price']) ) { // Checked GET request

            $pricesRange = $_GET['price'];

            preg_match_all('!\d+!', $pricesRange, $matches); // Extract only the numbers

            $rangeValue1 = $matches[0][0]; //preg_match_all returns multidimension array? 
            $rangeValue2 = $matches[0][1];

            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key'       => 'price',
                'value'     => array($rangeValue1, $rangeValue2 ),
                'type'      => 'DECIMAL',
                'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
            );
    }
```